# Submit button causes accordian div to collapse

Tags: php, jquery

I have a PHP page with an accordian (in a `div`) that opens three sections on the page. One of these sections is a contact form.

If a user neglects to submit a required field and hits `Submit` in the contact form, the error inside that div will not show because that div automatically collapses when the Submit button is pressed.

How do I get that div to stay open if an error message is shown?

[The website can be found here](http://davidkwhittemore.com/2013/index.php).

Comment: Take a look on you console(F12). There's an error saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: Validator is not defined` and is caught right on this line `var frmvalidator  = new Validator("contact_form");`. Did you forgot to include Validator library?

Comment: You are using some sort of validator in the page, but I'm not seeing any validator library which is causing a script error

Comment: In order for the page to work, if there is a validation error the page submit has to be prevented

Comment: Any code, or are you expecting me to click on a link I know nothing about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like the validation errors are coming from the server.  So I'm going to assume that the submit button is working as intended.  Since this is the case, you'll need to add

`$('#contactForm').parent().show();`  somewhere in your javascript

maybe something like this

```
    (function($) {
                  var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();
                  $('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
                    allPanels.slideUp();
                    $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
                    return false;
                  });

<? if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') { ?>
   $('#contactForm').parent().show(); 
<?}?>
                })(jQuery);
```

but only add this after the form has been submitted.

I don't do a lot of php, but the idea here is to get your php code to only emit the `$('#contactForm').parent().show();`  if it is a post.

Comment: That sounds correct to me. However, since the php on the page checks for errors in the contact form, that line script should be placed in the php somewhere? Any further help would be great as I'm not savvy with php or javascript. Thanks again.

Comment: it wouldn't be place in the php, per say, but in the html markup that the php is creating.  I'll update my answer with where the javascript should go